# JQuery - get the actual line number within js file

Tags: jquery

I use the code below to handle ajax call erros. I would like to add the line number of that `'$('body').append(...'` line to be abble to echo it out. By line number, I mean the line number within my .js file. Wondering if that is possible to get the actual line number? Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myfile.php",
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        $('body').append('aj.ERROR! [' + jqXHR.status + ' : ' + errorThrown + ']');
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // somecode
    }
});​
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011837/javascript-error-line-numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know to expose the current line number is with the `window.onerror` event handler, which has this signature:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) { ... }
```

so *in theory* you could trigger a real error in your code (`throw` ?) and then do your append in the error handler, e.g:

```
window.onerror = function(msg, url, line) {
    $('body').append(msg + ' at ' + url + ':' + line);
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myfile.php",
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        throw 'aj.ERROR! [' + jqXHR.status + ' : ' + errorThrown + ']';
    },
    success: function(data) {
        // somecode
    }
});​
```

**EDIT** it works (in Chrome, at least...) - http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/gLzY2/