# Why is Firefox error console showing two different line numbers?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

I'm using the newest Firefox for Ubuntu 14.04. I've noticed that sometimes the console can't show exactly the source of an error. For instance, right now I got a JavaScript "SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','" and the source in blue reads myfile.php:1:24. But when I click on the blue link, it opens the php file in the beginning, not showing any error at all.

What do the numbers 1 and 24 mean here? And why can't it show the exact location of the error?

Comment: Are you perhaps using some kind of temptating service which might include a javascript twice but on different levels of inheritance?

Comment: 1:24 means 24th character in line 1.

Comment: @CalleBergström I'm only using pure Javascript+PHP, no frameworks (not even know what a templating service is). The site is right now at localhost. I do some include_once, and yes, they might be the problem, since it happens after an ajax call.

Comment: @shanavasm line 1 of the file after it's been parsed, right? The way it shows in source-code or in the console, the first three lines read: "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='BR'>
<head>" So, there is no 24th character in any of them. If they mean the javascript lines, don't look like that either: "<script src='funcoes.js'></script><script type='text/javascript'>
var ajAnt = null;
function update() {
    if (HttpReq.readyState == 4 && HttpReq.status == 200) {" And if the error was in file funcoes.js, I think it would say so, right?

Comment: Line numbers do not always line up. If you have not coded back in the IE6 days where everything error seemed to be line 1 character 1, than you are "lucky".  When it points to the first line, normally it is (but not always) an issue with content that is being added dynamically. Add some console lines and/or set debugger statements and walk through the code to get a better idea where the error is coming from.

Comment: Hope this will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011837/javascript-error-line-numbers)

Comment: OK, I've found it! In my select: <select id='selForms' onchange='selFormsChange(this,\"".$_SESSION['cfg.frmdest']."\",$edit,\"esp\")'>
$edit was blank, so there was a gap between two colons, like in ..."S",,"esp"... That was 24th character of the onchange value. Weird error information, isn't it?

Comment: @shanavasm "If you want to get exact reason and location of error and if you want to perform extensive javascript debugging I would recommend you using FireBug." Strange, is it possible that FireBug was better in 2010 than is Firefox today, five years later?

Comment: IE11 shows correct line number for inline JavaScript errors.